# Filter a vector based on another vector

Tags: r, filter, tapply

I am trying to do something in R and it doesn't quite work, so I wanted to once more ask for advice here. I think the issue has to do with filtering a dataframe vs. filtering a vector, and I find posts related to my issue but not close enough for me to adapt the proposed solution to my problem.

I have a cross-national survey dataset, and I want to generate a vector that contains the means of the responses to a survey question, filtered by country. The country is given by a factor variable in the dataset. Basically, imagine a question "how many apples do you eat per day?" asked to people in two countries. I now want a vector consisting of the mean value for countries A and B.

To simulate:

```
y <- c(1,2,3,4,5,6)
z <- c("BE", "BE", "BE", "NL", "NL", "NL")
```

I now want a vector with two values, the average value of apples eaten by the Belgian respondents and the same for the Dutch respondents.

I tried something similar to this:

```
x <- c(mean(filter(data$dailyapples, z == 'BE')), mean(filter(data$dailyapples, z == 'NL')
```

But it gives me this error:

```
Error in UseMethod("filter") : 
  no applicable method for 'filter' applied to an object of class "c('double', 'numeric')"
```

As I said, I think it has something to do with filtering vectors vs. filtering dataframes, but that doesn't solve the issue yet. If anyone can help me, and ideally also explain briefly why `filter` doesn't work, it'd be much appreciated!

Comment: You need a group by approach `tapply(y, z, FUN = mean)` `filter` from `dplyr` requires a data.frame/tibble and not a vector (`data$dailyapples` is a vector

Comment: If you want to use `filter`, the code would be `library(dplyr);data %>% filter(z == 'BE') %>% summarise(Mean = mean(dailyapples))` or for more than one, `data %>% filter(z %in% c('BE', 'NL')) %>% group_by(z) %>% summarise(Mean = mean(dailyapplies, na.rm = TRUE))`

Comment: `filter` is for extracting a single subset. Grouping functions are for the task you are posing.

Comment: Great, I will look into those functions and see if I can get it to work. Many thanks!